# Where to find the file that generates the custom options in a new order email?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional

I want to find the file that generates the highlighted area.

[image: new order email]

I have tried order_new_guest.html which is located in **app/locale/en_US/template/email/sale**

But it only shows the 4 table areas above the highlighted area

Comment: check at app\design\frontend\yourpackage\your template\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml and app\design\frontend\ourpackage\your template\template\email\order\items.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

Take a look at /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
```

You could also enable 
[magento template path hints](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento)